# Undefined Method Error When Calling .sort_by on Second Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Contacts model with two date columns. In this case birthday and family_anniversary. When I call a .sort_by on the queries pulling the dates in the next 90 days I get the below error.

**Error:**
`undefined method 'birthday_within_90_days' for #<Array:0x007f934fff1dd0>`

**Troubleshooting:**
I have commented out the .sort_by on each call and when I do that the other works. The best I have been able to figure out is this is related to ActiveRecord and Arrays. My suspicion is I cannot sort two arrays pulled from the same model. However I am novice and this is an area I am totally in the dark on.

My **Model** code, please note I am using the RailsLove/birthday gem which is where I am getting the `find_#{column_name}_for` method.

```
def next_birthday
  year = Date.today.year
  mmdd = birthday.strftime('%m%d')
  year += 1 if mmdd < Date.today.strftime('%m%d')
  mmdd = '0301' if mmdd == '0229' && !Date.parse("#{year}0101").leap?
  return Date.parse("#{year}#{mmdd}")
end

def next_anniversary
  year = Date.today.year
  mmdd = family_anniversary.strftime('%m%d')
  year += 1 if mmdd < Date.today.strftime('%m%d')
  mmdd = '0301' if mmdd == '0229' && !Date.parse("#{year}0101").leap?
  return Date.parse("#{year}#{mmdd}")
end

def self.anniversary_within_90_days
  find_family_anniversaries_for((Date.today), (Date.today + 90.days)).sort_by(&:next_anniversary)
end

def self.birthday_within_90_days
  find_birthdays_for((Date.today), (Date.today + 90.days)).sort_by(&:next_birthday)
end
```

I realize this is not DRY. That will be a different question for a different day.

My **Controller** code is:

```
def dates
  @user = current_user
  contact_ids = @user.contacts.pluck(:id)

  @contacts = Contact
  @contacts = @contacts.where(id: contact_ids.uniq)
  @contacts = @contacts.anniversary_within_90_days
  @contacts = @contacts.birthday_within_90_days
  @children = @user.children
  @pets     = @user.pets
end
```

My **View** code:

```
<div data-equalizer class="row">
  <div data-equalizer-watch class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
    <%= render "layouts/sidenav" %>
  </div>
  <div data-equalizer-watch class="medium-9 columns contacts-list show-for-medium-up">
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
      <li>
        <h3>Birthdays in the next 90 Days</h3>
         <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
          <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <% if contact.birthday.present? %>
              <%= link_to "#{contact.first_name} #{contact.last_name}", contact %> <strong><%= contact.birthday.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y") %></strong> (<%= contact.birthday_age %> years old)
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li>
    <h3>Children's Birthdays in the next 90 Days</h3>
    <% @children.each do |child| %>
      <ul style="list-style:none;">
       <% if child.child_birthday.present? %>
        <%= child.name %> <strong><%= child.child_birthday.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y") %></strong> (<%= child.child_birthday_age %> years old)
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Anniversaries in the next 90 Days</h3>
    <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
      <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <% if contact.family_anniversary.present? %>
            <%= link_to "#{contact.first_name} #{contact.last_name}", contact %> <strong><%= contact.family_anniversary.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y") %></strong> has been married for <%= contact.family_anniversary_age %> years.
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <h3>Pets Born in the next 90 Days</h3>
        <% @pets.each do |pet| %>
          <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <% if pet.birthday.present? %>
              <%= pet.name %> <strong><%=pet.birthday.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%Y") %></strong> (<%= pet.birthday_age %> years old)
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any hints on how to fix this are appreciated.

Comment: as I described in my answer. but to make it clear - remove the self's because you call the method as an instance method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DON'T DO WHAT I DID**

This is smelly code that will perform poorly in the long run. Since there are many dates in the app spread across several relationships it is better to use Single Table Inheritance to increase performance when running look ups and sorts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know when using Class- and Instance- methods?

```
@contact = Contact.first # creates an instance of Contact
@contact.birthday_within_90_days

class Contact
  def birthday_within_90_days
    ..
  end
end
```

works.

An as Class method you write and use the following code

```
@contacts = Contact.birthday_within_90_days

class Contact
  def self.birthday_within_90_days
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @devanand for the clarification.

I used the Class method and it results in the error going away, but its showing all values for all contacts versus just the users contacts. The second list is still not sorted.

I used the Instance method (which I think is the right direction) and I get `undefined method 'anniversary_within_90_days' for #<Contact::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff69e5028e0>` so the methods in my model is not coming through.

Comment: For anyone in the future [this is a good link digging into the difference between Instance and Class methods](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)